erro de import com python
nao estou conseguindo executar esse codigo pois da erro de module , o projeto esta inteiro nessa pasta , mas mesmo assim nao executa nem o init.py e nem o app.py

apresenta esse erro ao executar


    from ticketing_system import db, login_manager
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ticketing_system'



ARQUIVO APP.PY


from ticketing_system import create_app
app = create_app()
if name == "main":
app.run(debug=True) ```


Possivelmente você copiou esse código de import de algum lugar, sem entender de fato o que ele deveria ser, ou então você pegou algum projeto existente, mas apenas parcialmente. Esse módulo provavelmente é uma pasta que deveria existir no projeto, mas se copiou isso de algum lugar, então está errado.

se é algo que tentou criar por conta, é provavel que o nivel das pastas que você organizou os arquivos esteja errado, então é por isso que deve primeiro estudar os fundamentos da linguagem: 1) https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Relacionado: Para que serve o arquivo __init__.py em módulos no python?

Relacionado: Como colocar um módulo Python numa pasta diferente do meu script?

A conversa se estendeu e por isso foi movida para o chat.
